# Is the human body more than perfectly efficient?

Tags: energy, biophysics

The average person weighs about $700\,\text N$. If they run $5,000\,\text m$, the formula for work says they do $700\,\text N \cdot 5,000\,\text m = 3.5\,\text{MJ}$ of work, or $836.5\,\text{kCal}$ of work. But most fitness trackers would say that this person burned $300-400\,\text{kCal}$. This means the human body would be 200% efficient, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Your formula for the work done applies to a person running up a 5000 m hill.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is not your weight that makes you to run.

When calculating work done, you must specifically use the force that is doing the work. That has to be a force *in the same direction* as the displacement, so horisontal. So it is not your weight that does the work. Your weight does zero work (unless you also have a displacement vertically).

Rather, the force you need is that of static friction with the ground, which corresponds to the (horizontal) muscle force from thighs and legs and other body parts. This might not be easy to calculate, though. Also note that apart from the actual force produced to push you forwards, plenty of energy is simultaneously lost, i.e. as heat, to compress and extend muscle fibres, to raise your heart rate etc.

The human body is in fact generally quite an inefficient machine since a lot of energy is spent in order to produce the force which does the work that moves you forwards.

Answer (score 2):

The correct formula for the work is
$$W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}$$

The gravitational force is directed downwards, while $d\vec{s}$ is horizontal (if you are running in plain). As a consequence the scalar product is always null and you are not doing work against the gravitational force.

The energy you consume while running goes into the work needed to overcome the friction with the ground. If the ground were very low friction, you could just slide and cover long distances with low effort. Additionally, when you move the muscles heat up, and this is a great waste of energy.

You could say that humans are not at all efficient at covering long distances by running on a flat surface. Just think how effortless would be to do the same on a bicycle, that's way more efficient in terms of energy consumption.

The reason is that we didn't evolve to run on a flat road. We evolved to move in irregular ground, through mud, grass, rocks, leaves, trees, cliffs and hills... Try to do that on a bicycle!